# ¿Viene "coña" de "coño" etimológicamente?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, vulgaridades

La palabra "[coña](https://dle.rae.es/co%C3%B1a)" no es malsonante, y relativamente común en el habla cotidiana (al menos en España cf. *"ni de coña"* ).

Por eso me sorprende que [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co%C3%B1a) diga que viene etimológicamente de "coño", una palabra un poquito más vulgar.

¿Es esta su etimología verdadera? En caso contrario, ¿cuál es?

Comment: Coña puede ser considerada malsonante en algunos ambientes en España

Comment: Más información: [*Diccionario y aprendizaje del español*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xnwGv1NKwFIC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=%22co%C3%B1a%22) (p.348 etc)

Comment: Alguna gente mayor (de 80 años) lo considera malsonante, aunque bien es cierto, que se usa tanto que la mayor parte de la gente no

Comment: Por qué el downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Pues parece que la cosa no está clara. Efectivamente, el DLE parece que prefiere [no aventurarse](https://dle.rae.es/co%C3%B1a) a dar ningún origen etimológico, aunque algunos autores parece que lo tienen más claro. Veamos las opciones...

En primer lugar tenemos a Corominas, que en su diccionario etimológico cita *coña* como derivado de *coño*, aunque no dice nada más, ni siquiera en qué año se comenzó a usar como suele ser habitual en sus entradas. Otros autores parecen apoyarlo, especificando que se trata de una variante eufemística de *coño*, la cual se usaba como interjección por las mujeres (igual que se usa *coñe* con el mismo propósito).

Por otro lado, buscando en el *Fichero general* de la RAE encuentro algunos textos que relacionan la palabra *coña* con el quechua *ckoña* (la transcripción varía según la ficha), que significa "moco, secreción de la mucosa nasal". Buscando en un [diccionario de quechua](https://aulex.org/qu-es/?busca=qhu%C3%B1a) he comprobado que la palabra existe realmente (allí transcrita como *qhuña*). En todo caso, no sé si existe relación con esta voz *coña* y la de la pregunta.

Otra posibilidad más remota es que tenga algo que ver con las *coñas*, como se denomina en el sur de España a una especie de [caracol marino](http://bibliotecadigital.ilce.edu.mx/sites/ciencia/volumen2/ciencia3/087/htm/sec_15.htm) (al menos en Málaga y Cádiz por lo que he leído). Este uso de la palabra se documenta ya en un texto de 1926, anterior a los primeros casos del uso de *coña* como el referido en la pregunta. En todo caso, es muy probable que el nombre vulgar de este caracol provenga de su similitud con la vulva:

> También es comestible, por su pie musculoso, grande y de color rosado, la "coña" *(Cymbium papillatum)*.

En este caso estaríamos pues en la situación propuesta por Corominas. Lo curioso es que la voz *coña* en Andalucía también parece denominar a una especie de cangrejo, al menos en la provincia de Granada según el *Vocabulario andaluz* de Alcalá Venceslada. Y, según el mismo documento, en la provincia de Jaén denominaría a un "tocado masculino de paño, generalmente de picote, que cubre toda la cabeza y el cuello, abrochándose debajo de la barba. Úsanlo principalmente los pastores".

Por último, en otro texto, el *Vocabulario murciano* de Alberto Sevilla, publicado en 1919, aparece *[coña](https://books.google.es/books?id=pwgWAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA61&dq=%22co%C3%B1a%22&hl=es&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q=%22co%C3%B1a%22&f=false)* con el significado de "gorra de muchacho, con visera y dos cintas cortas que cuelgan por detrás". Y es particularmente interesante porque el mismo texto recoge ya la acepción de "burla, vaya, mofa" para la voz. Se indica además que en valenciano existiría también *conya* con el mismo significado de "gorra". Es el texto más antiguo que he encontrado hasta ahora que recoge la acepción actual de la palabra, anterior incluso al primer caso que encuentro en el CORDE, que es de 1938:

> *"Voy a darle una receta: más coña, menos coño y ninguna caña". Y con aquello quería decir que me divirtiese, pero que frecuentara menos las mujeres y que me abstuviese en absoluto del alcohol.*
>
> Enrique Serpa, "Contrabando", 1938 (Cuba).

Resumiendo: la opción más plausible es la de que sea un derivado de *coño*, pero opciones hay suficientes como para no poder precisar con rotundidad que eso sea así.